# Creating a real estate price index for a given location

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics

I have a dataset with property sales data for a city for the last several years. I am attempting to create a price index, but struggling to find any examples in code or even those same algorithms applied in other sectors. From what I understand, the main algorithms to use are RSR, Case-Shiller and hedonic regression. Maybe there are other methods? But again, there's nothing available that I managed to come across online, all ML work I have looked at so far is aimed at estimating values of individual properties. Would appreciate if anyone could suggest something helpful.

Also, what other factors should I consider and what methods to look at?

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts on this very interesting issue:

1. I don't really understand how or why you would use Machine Learning for this. You are not trying to predict or to find a pattern, but rather to simplify a dataset with high complexity into a single number which stays comparable over time.
2. As stated previously, the complexity of the reality you are trying to study is extremely high, and there are many, many things that have to be taken into account.

For instance, a long term index could face the following problem: over a few decades, the average house size can vary significantly. That could drive the prices up or down, but it would be produced by a change in the house attributes, not on the valuation given by the market. Prices would go up because houses would be better, and your index should account for that.

3. The construction of the index will force you to take decisions that will probably skew the index in some direction. There's hardly a single, *best* solution for the problem, and different solutions will deal differently with situations like the one I explained in the previous point.

Finally, I would recommend you to do some reading. Institutions with price indexes usually publish their methodologies, and you can learn a lot from them. I suggest [this](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/documents/7590317/0/Technical-Manual-OOH-HPI-2017/) by Eurostat. [This](http://www.ine.es/daco/daco42/ipv/metodologia.pdf) one by the spanish National Institute of Statistics is very good and concise, but is in spanish.

By the way, you can probably find better answers to this question in [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).